# Managing auto generated HTTP Authorization Manager in jmeter not working

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a native app in jmeter. It shows one auto-generated 'Authorization Manager' where username is appearing as '${Auth_Login}' and password as `${Auth_password}`.

I am running the script but the response is appearing as :

```
"{"error":"No authorization header."}"
```

[image]

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the token which returns from the first response using a post processor (i.e [regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)).

Now add this token to the next request's header manager like this:

- **Name:** Authorization
- **Value:** ${Token}

Note: you should check the request header using traffic capturing tool i.e fiddler, because these names might not be the same also the token sometimes looks like this `Bearer ${Token}`

See [using regex with jmeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) for more information on regular expression extractor.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.

Comment: But my problem still remains, I tried with fiddler but it didn't solve my problem. And to extract value there is three types of values are which is: access token, token type & refresh token. I tried with all these but it's not working.

Comment: Okay you need to extract the access token, then on fiddler check the header of the request, you will be able to see the authorization header details(something like Authorization: access token), now on jmeter add the  same to your header manager with changing the token to the variable you extracted.